# NetBeans 7 no suggestions on JSTL tag

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, jstl

I've created, from scratch, a new project to test a .jsp page with some JSTL tags.

However in NB the suggestions doesn't work.

If I type `<c:` nothing happen...

I've imported from glassfish 3.1 the module jstl-impl.jar but also nothing work.

In a strange way, if I create a web project from NB the auto-complete works!!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must start/import your project as web project in order to get Java web feature enabled. And I can see you are fine when you start a web project. So, why not just go that route. Where is the problem?

Comment: Strange enough that only for that tags I must create a web project while if I create a simple Java project and then use .jsp constructs the suggestions works (scriptlets, directive etc.).

Comment: Strange, indeed. To me its not letting me choose to create JSP page in a Java Project.

Comment: Only for comment I think that NB 7 is buggy and not complete concerning the JSTL. For example every time I use a JSTL tag it put a taglib directive in the page... and it doesn't suggest the tags attributes...